# How to create a scatter plot legend with only one symbol for each label?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

How can I create a scatter plot legend without two symbols showing up each time? I can understand why you'd want this when you're joining symbols by lines, but for a pure scatter plot, all I want in the legend is one example of the symbol. This plot from a previous stackoverflow post shows the kind of thing I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In the `legend` command you can use the `scatterpoints` option:

```
ax.legend(loc=0, scatterpoints = 1)
```

For a normal plot, it is the option `numpoints`.

Here you can find more information about the keyword arguments for the legend: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend